# Calculate change in value window function when the identifier has dropped of the current period

Tags: sql-server, window-functions, running-totals

I was wondering how can i got about finding the change in value from one period to another but in my scenario the identifier has dropped off the current period.

I'm think this could be done with a cte and a select distinct id but i'm not sure how to implement.

Some demo date below

```
CREATE TABLE basic_pays (
    employee_id int,
    fiscal_year INT,
    salary DECIMAL(10 , 2 ),
    PRIMARY KEY (employee_id, fiscal_year)
);

INSERT INTO basic_pays(employee_id, fiscal_year,salary) VALUES(1,2017,24000);
INSERT INTO basic_pays(employee_id, fiscal_year,salary) VALUES(2,2017,17000);
INSERT INTO basic_pays(employee_id, fiscal_year,salary) VALUES(1,2018,25920);

SELECT 
    employee_id, 
    fiscal_year,
    salary,
    salary - LAG(salary) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id ORDER BY fiscal_year) salary_change
FROM
    basic_pays
GROUP BY 
    employee_id, fiscal_year, salary
ORDER BY fiscal_year, employee_id

DROP TABLE basic_pays
```

The expected output would be

```
| employee_id | fiscal_year | salary   | salary_change |
|-------------|-------------|----------|---------------|
| 1           | 2017        | 24000.00 | NULL          |
| 2           | 2017        | 17000.00 | NULL          |
| 1           | 2018        | 25920.00 | 1920.00       |
| 2           | 2018        | 0.00     | -17000.00     |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You could do it like this, performance wise this could hurt on bigger datasets.**

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT employee_id,a.fiscal_year
from basic_pays
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT distinct fiscal_year 
from basic_pays
) as a)


SELECT   c.employee_id, 
    c.fiscal_year,
    CASE WHEN salary IS NULL then 0.00 else salary END as salary,
    CASE WHEN salary IS NULL then 0.00 else salary END - LAG(salary) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY c.employee_id ORDER BY c.fiscal_year) salary_change
FROM
    CTE c
LEFT JOIN basic_pays b
ON C.employee_id = b.employee_id
AND c.fiscal_year= b.fiscal_year;
```

**Result**

```
employee_id fiscal_year    salary       salary_change
1             2017        24000.00      NULL
1             2018        25920.00      1920.00
2             2017        17000.00      NULL
2             2018        NULL          -17000.00
```

Comment: That's along the lines i first thought, but interesting that you think it could hurt performance.... that's concerning.... what is the obvious workaround here? is that the calendar table suggested in comments?

Comment: @GlennSampson yes the calender table, other ideas could be creating a secondary table and filling it with the CTE results on non production hours, .... In general self joins are not something the optimizer works well with. Certain indexes can help to improve this query.

Comment: @GlennSampson *is that the calendar table suggested in comments?* The query assumes that there is at least one record for each year in REAL table. In modelling case it can give holes, of course (edit your sample data, replace 2018 to 2019 to look at). If source table is huge enough, than it is more safe to generate such years table in recursive CTE based on MIN(fiscal_year) and MAX(fiscal_year) of source table as borders (especially when there exists proper index).

Comment: @Akina I see what you are saying... so is it suggested i create a calendar table then  `CROSS APPLY` onto this table?

Comment: @GlennSampson I think that static calendar table with year granularity may be excess. It is too small, so there is no difference in performance between static, statically generated (SELECT 2017 UNION SELECT 2018) and dynamically generated (recursive CTE) tables. And indexing cannot help - fullscan will be more effective until at least 10-5 year data analyzing. Additionally you must remember, that at Jan 1, 00:00 you must to add one more year to the table...

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest to use a Calendar table for this purpose.

I've simulated it by using a table value. And if you have a single row by employee_id/fiscal year, you can avoid GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT 
    emp_id, 
    fy,
    salary,
    COALESCE(salary,0) - LAG(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY fy) salary_change
FROM
    -- all combinations of year / employee_id
    (SELECT 
         emp_id, fy 
     FROM 
         (VALUES (2017),(2018)) as calendar(fy)
     CROSS JOIN
         -- it should be SELECT employee_id from employee's table
         (SELECT DISTINCT employee_id as emp_id FROM basic_pays) e) cal     LEFT JOIN
    basic_pays bp
    ON bp.employee_id = cal.emp_id
    AND bp.fiscal_year = cal.fy
ORDER BY 
    fy, emp_id
```

> ```
> emp_id |   fy | salary   | salary_change
> -----: | ---: | :------- | :------------
>      1 | 2017 | 24000.00 | null         
>      2 | 2017 | 17000.00 | null         
>      1 | 2018 | 25920.00 | 1920.00      
>      2 | 2018 | null     | -17000.00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=01cd02273ac45082a727d92f47cc87c5)*